# When trying to produce a JSON Array with Apache Wink I get WebApplicationException

Tags: java, json, apache, tomcat6, jax-rs

i'm new to JAX-RS. I'm trying to represent a List to a JSON array:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getUsersResource/{userId}")
public List<AbstractResource> getUsersResources(@PathParam("userId") final String userId) {
    if (userId == null) {
        return null;
    }

    User user = null;

    try {
        user = userDao.getUserById(Integer.parseInt(userId));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        user = userDao.getUser(userId);
    }

    if (user == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return abstractResourceDao.getUsersResources(null, user.userId);
}
```

When i execute this url i get:

> {"exception": {"name": "WebApplicationException"}}

I annotated my AbstractResource class with the @XmlRootElement only and when i change the @Produces annotation parameter to

> @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

I get the proper result. Here is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.balthaser.b3e.rest.RESTApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Client</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.balthaser.b3e.rest.client.RESTClient</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Client</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/index.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Are there any additional requirements when producing JSON Arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Wink is using json.org and jettison as a Json provider and they can't handle Java List properly. 
So you need to configure Wink to use Jackson instead as a Json provider.

Here is the detail.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wa-aj-jackson/index.html